# How to add a timeline bar in a shiny app to show the progress of an animated ggplot through the years?

Tags: r, shiny, gganimate

So, I was just able to figure out how to create an animated graph using ggplot and gganimate in shiny. However, my efforts to add a timeline bar at the bottom of the graph has been fruitless so far. Here is my Shiny code and data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
    imageOutput("myImage")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myImage <- renderImage({

    Data <- tribble(
  ~LinkIDs, ~Year2001Traffic, ~Year2002Traffic, ~Year2003Traffic,
  "A", 1, 10, 15,
  "B", 3, 1, 10,
  "C", 10, 5, 1)

    Data <- Data %>% gather(Year, Traffic, -LinkIDs)
    Data <- Data %>% mutate(Year= as.integer(parse_number(Year)))

    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.gif')


    p1 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = LinkIDs, y = Traffic)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = 'blue', fill="white") +
      labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'Link ID', y = 'Volume') + 
      transition_time(Year)

    anim_save("outfile.gif", animate(p1, fps = 1, duration = 3))

    list(src = "outfile.gif",
         contentType = 'image/gif'
    )}, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So, What I want to have is a timeline bar similar to the one below the gapminder plot on the bottom of this page to be able to play/start/stop the animation:

https://towardsdatascience.com/animating-your-data-visualizations-like-a-boss-using-r-f94ae20843e3

Can someone please help me with this? any help is appreciated.

Comment: An example: http://lenkiefer.com/2018/08/11/state-employment-dataviz/

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an animated bar plot example with my first search. With points it works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotlyOutput("myImage")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myImage <- renderPlotly({

    Data <- tribble(
      ~LinkIDs, ~Year2001Traffic, ~Year2002Traffic, ~Year2003Traffic,
      "A", 1, 10, 15,
      "B", 3, 1, 10,
      "C", 10, 5, 1)

    Data <- Data %>% gather(Year, Traffic, -LinkIDs)
    Data <- Data %>% mutate(Year= as.integer(parse_number(Year)))

    p1 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = LinkIDs, y = Traffic)) +
      geom_point(aes(frame = Year),stat = "identity", color = 'blue', fill="white")# +
      #labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'Link ID', y = 'Volume')

    ggplotly(p1)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander. I had actually tried a similar code, but I was hoping someone could help me figure out a way to make a **bar** plot with a timeline similar to the one in the link I shared in the original question. I guess I need to do some more research.